# How to have multiple "To replace" special characters in xsl translate

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

How can I replace all the dash and dot on my string with a slash? I've tried using the below code.

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate('string_name', '-.', '/')"/>
```

I've also tried using the "|" but both codes don't work

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate('string_name', '-|.|', '/')"/>
```

Does anyone know a way to do this? Thank you.

I'm expecting to remove all the dots and dashes on my string and be replace by slash.

Comment: What does "not work" mean in your particular case? What output do you get? Is it maybe "string_name" instead of the actual value of your string_name field (as @y.arazim mentioned, you probably do not want a quoted string literal there)

Comment: I was a little bemused by the question: how come the answer is difficult to find? So I googled a bit, and discovered that both the MDN and w3schools descriptions of the translate() function are appallingly bad. I would recommend that you become familiar with the W3 specification, which is perfectly readable, though I say so myself,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you want:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate('string_name', '-.', '//')"/>
```

(that is, one replacement character for each character in the string of characters to be replaced).

And you probably do not want to quote the reference to the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you are really using a product supporting XSLT 2 then you have access to the XPath 2 function `replace` which would work as `replace($string, '[-.]', '/')`.